# Ridaex TV's Android 4.4 version doesn't support applications

Tags: android-tv, led, television, smart-tv

**Ridaex TV** comes with Android 4.4 operating system but when I'm trying to install applications from Google Play Store a message pops up saying **"Application Unsupported"**.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error message is that the Android Operating System in the older versions of Ridaex TV had `Android 4.4` version, wherein the latest Ridaex TVs come with `Android 8.0` version.

I too had the same question, and later realized that I had to:

1. Download a 3rd party website like appsapk
2. Transfer the apk file onto the usb device
3. Plugin the usb to the TV
4. Select the application to be installed
5. Click install.

Answer (score 0):

Even i have faced the same issue with my Brother's home Ridaex TV.  But i have installed some apps from Google Play. Few of them were unsupported, i have to download them from appsapk and install it via USB device.